# Understanding $\chi^2$ in plain language

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, distance

Suppose I was trying to explain what $\chi^2$ is and why it's important to my grandma. I want to give core intuition to this formula:

$$\chi^2 = \sum_{i}\frac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}$$

1. I would tell her that the aim is to measure the discrepancy between what is known/observed in the real world (observed values $O_i$) and what it is expected from the real world according to our theories/models ($E_i$ values). In that way we can know how far off is our description of reality from the actual facts. Thus we must look out for the difference between theory and observations, or $O_i-E_i$.
2. Now, usually there's not just one observation and one prediction to match, but many. That's where the sum comes in: $\sum_i (O_i-E_i)$.
3. But think about this for a moment. We don't really care if our predictions are overestimating or underestimating reality, but by how much they are away from reality. Thus we don't really want to know the sign of the difference $O_i-E_i$. This prompts us to use the absolute value of the difference, $|O_i-E_i|$, or perhaps squaring it, $(O_i-E_i)^2$, so that the information about the sign is lost. Also in this way we prevent the summation to make overestimates of our theory ($O_i-E_i < 0$) compensate the underestimates ($O_i-E_i > 0$), which would give us the false belief that our theory was describing the world in an accurate manner when it is actually not. Let's choose to use the square for the moment (the reason why one would prefer this would be apparent in a minute). So now we have
   $$\sum_{i}(O_i-E_i)^2$$
4. But wait a minute, actually using $O_i-E_i$ as a way of quantifying the discrepancy between observations and theoretical predictions is a bit problematic. If $O_i-E_i$ that doesn't necessarily mean that I should consider my predictions to fit my data badly; perhaps $O_i$ and $E_i$ are themselves huge and the discrepancy is not that relatively large. Also if $O_i$ and $E_i$ are very small numbers it is probable that their difference will also be a small number, but our expectations might be far off in proportion to its size from the actual observed values. Thus we are not really interested in $O_i-E_i$ but in that difference in relation to the expected values $E_i$. What we want to use as our metric for discrepancy is actually the relative difference (in percentage) $(O_i-E_i)/E_i$. With all of this in mind our way of quantifying the total discrepancy between predictions and observations is

$$\chi^2 = \sum_{i}\left(\frac{O_i-E_i}{E_i}\right)^2$$

5. But look at that! This is actually the same expression you would have for the Euclidean distance between two points in an $n$-dimensional space, by using Pythagoras theorem. So we can interpret $\chi$ to be the relative distance between theory and observations in an $n$-dimensional space build of predictions and actual data. Isn't that an amazing way of looking at it? We actually never care to compute this distance, $$\chi = \sqrt{\sum_{i}\left(\frac{O_i-E_i}{E_i}\right)^2}$$ because in reality $\chi^2$ will have the same minimum as $\chi$ (even if the value at that minimum would not be the same obviously). Usually we want to minimize $\chi$ because that means shrinking the relative distance between theory and observations (with this process we build a good theory/model for our data; one that fits it the best it can). So minimizing $\chi$ or $\chi^2$ is actually the same thing, with the added bonus that minimizing $\chi^2$ allows you to compute it faster (since you don't have to calculate the square root of the whole thing).
6. But there's a problem (**and finally here is my question**), the actual formula for Pearson's $\chi^2$ is $$\chi^2 = \sum_{i}\frac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}$$, which is not the formula that we found. What is this last conceptual step that one has to make to understand this thing? Why is the denominator $E_i$ instead of its square? I've read somewhere that actually $\chi$ is not an Euclidean distance but can still be understood as some kind of distance in the space of predictions and observations, a [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) perhaps. What does that mean? Is it true? What intuitive explanation would you give for this last step towards full understanding of Pearson's $\chi^2$?